# Open Image Link with Credential

Tags: python, html, image, powerbi, report

i have a multiple csv file with one image link column. the link itself will redirect to a login page before we are able to see the image.

is there any method to bypass this login page and just go straight into the image? like for example when i click the link it will straight open the image / i would be able to show those link as image directly in power bi.

i have tried just using power bi and convert it to image link.
and when i click it, it will open the new tab to the login page

what i want is that from the power bi report/ html/ or any interface we can show this image directly  without clicking the link, open a new tab, or reentering credential

Comment: Please don't use all caps in the heading.

Comment: changed it. do you have any other input regarding this inquiry. would greatly appreciate it

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/power-bi-images-tables, this method normally works, but you have an additional credential issue. might need to scrap it with python and store it in sharepoint first.